# How to loop through these pages and scrape information from each one?

Tags: python, selenium

I am new to programming and need some help with my web-crawler.

At the moment, I have my code opening up every web-page in the list. However, I wish to extract information from each one it loads. This is what I have.

```
from selenium import webdriver;
import csv;

driver = webdriver.Firefox();

driver.get("https://www.betexplorer.com/baseball/usa/mlb-2018/results/? 
stage=KvfZSOKj&month=all")
links_code : list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@class="in-match"]');
first_two : list = links_code[0:2];
first_two_links : list = [];

i : int;
for i in first_two:
    link = i.get_attribute("href");
    first_two_links.append(link);

odds : list = [];
i :int;
for i in first_two_links:
    driver.get(i);
    o = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="table-main__detail- 
    odds--hasarchive"]');
    odds.append(o);

**Error:** NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: 
//span[@class="table-main__detail- odds--hasarchive"]
```

I am just looking to scrape the first two links at the moment so that it is easier to manage. However, I can't seem to figure out a way around this error.

It seems to me as if the error indicates that it is searching the x_path in the home page, rather than the link it follows.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is it python code?

Comment: It works for me, I used Chrome instead of Firefox since I have that binary handy. (I added a line to print `odds` and it prints a list of 2 `selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement`'s as expected) When I copy-pasted your code, I saw you have spaces in `"table-main__detail-     odds--hasarchive"` that you should remove.